# How do I find out the Windows 10 build number in Wix?

Tags: c#, xml, wix

I have a program that only runs on Windows 10 builds greater than a specific version. Is there any way to detect the build version during installation with a Wix condition and deny installation if the build number is too low?

VersionNT does not work as it is not specific enough to know that the user is using Windows 10.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3202260/versionnt-value-for-windows-10-and-windows-server-2016